# HTML POST and fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

I have two problems here:
**1.** I have a problem with the value of the checkbox
                                                                                          **2.** I have a problem with the mysql_fetch_array($variable, ASSOC); method --> all the data from my database are VARCHAR type

**1.** All the variable with, at the end 'Cb', signified that this value is from a checkbox of a FORM. If a checkbox is checked, it means that the row (ex: Username) will be in the Select method for my Database (ex: SELECT Username FROM...)

I receive this Error
1. Undefined index: fonctionCb in C:\wamp\www\Projet Compte Utilisateur\manip_liste.php on line 7
2. Undefined variable: tab in C:\wamp\www\Projet Compte Utilisateur\manip_liste.php on line 14
...etc from all the checkbox **if they are not checked** .. here is my PHP code

```
<?php   
$prep = "";

if(!$_POST['username'])
    echo 'Nom d\'utilisateur manquant';

if(($_POST["userCb"]) && ($_POST["suffixeCb"]) && ($_POST["fonctionCb"]) && ($_POST["passwordCb"])){
    $prep = " * ";
    $tab = "User    SUFFIXE     SITE    FONCTION    PASSWD";
}
else{   
        if($_POST["userCb"]){
            $prep += "username ,";
            $tab += "USER   ";
        }           
        if($_POST["suffixeCb"]){
            $prep += "suffixe ,";
            $tab += "SUFFIXE    ";
        }   
        if($_POST["passwordCb"]){
            $prep += "password ,";
            $tab += "PASSWD ";
        }
        if($_POST["siteCb"]){
            $prep += "siteWeb ,";
            $tab += "SITE   ";
        }
        if($_POST["fonctionCb"]){
            $prep += "fonction ";
            $tab += "Fx ";
        }
    }//ELSE

require("db_action.php");   //Require in the database connection.
$bd = db_open();
$data = db_select($prep,  $_POST["username"]); //Envoie des variables à afficher et du Username pour le SELECT

echo "'$tab'";
echo "'$data'";    ?>
```

**2.** The second ERROR
and also I got this error from the fetch_array method
Error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\Projet Compte Utilisateur\db_action.php on line 68

Here is the code from my method

```
function db_select($prep, $username){

        $querycon = "SELECT '$prep' FROM info_compte WHERE username = '$username'";
        if(!mysql_query($querycon)){
            echo "Il n\'y a aucun '$username' dans la base de données";
            $response = "";
        }
        else{
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($querycon), MYSQL_ASSOC))
                    printf("%s  %s  %s  %s  %s", $row["username"], $row["suffixe"], $row["password"], $row["siteWeb"], $row["fonction"]);  //The PRINTF dont work 
            }

        return $response;   
}//db_select
```

Thank you all to answer and i specify that i'm a beginner in practice who wants to learn ..

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not my intention

Comment: @ThorDozer: You should be concatenating strings with `.=` rather than `+=`. Also, try using something along the lines of `isset()` to check if a value is set. And I'm assuming your `$tab` variable is not being set as that if conditional is failing, therefore your attempts at concatenating are throwing errors.

Comment: @Russel Dias: What do you mean with the isset(); method. Where should i put it?

Comment: @ThorDozer: Any variable you are testing the existence of.

Comment: First Question is already answered. The second is still appearing

Comment: @ThorDozer: Answered. I think...

Comment: @ThorDozer I've added a big update to my answer that should help you make progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part 1, one problem is that you may have a trailing comma on the end of $prep depending on what columns you end up selecting.  To solve this try the below code (note I've added backticks around your column names, it's good practice but not required).  The `isset()` function checks if a variable actually exists.  Currently you are trying to access variables that may not exist, hence the errors.

```
<?php   
$prep = array();
$tab = '';

if(!isset($_POST['username']))
    echo 'Nom d\'utilisateur manquant';

if(isset($_POST["userCb"]) && isset($_POST["suffixeCb"]) && isset($_POST["fonctionCb"]) && isset($_POST["passwordCb"])){
    $prep[] = "*";
    $tab = "User    SUFFIXE     SITE    FONCTION    PASSWD";
}
else{   
        if(isset($_POST["userCb"])){
            $prep[] = "`username`";
            $tab .= "USER   ";
        }           
        if(isset($_POST["suffixeCb"])){
            $prep[] = "`suffixe`";
            $tab .= "SUFFIXE    ";
        }   
        if(isset($_POST["passwordCb"])){
            $prep[] = "`password`";
            $tab .= "PASSWD ";
        }
        if(isset($_POST["siteCb"])){
            $prep[] = "`siteWeb`";
            $tab .= "SITE   ";
        }
        if(isset($_POST["fonctionCb"])){
            $prep[] = "`fonction`";
            $tab .= "Fx ";
        }
    }//ELSE

// This line glues the pieces of the $prep array back together
$prep = implode(',', $prep);

require("db_action.php");   //Require in the database connection.
$bd = db_open();
$data = db_select($prep,  $_POST["username"]); //Envoie des variables à afficher et du Username pour le SELECT

echo "'$tab'";
echo "'$data'";    ?>
```

For your part 2 error, you have to assign the return of the `mysql_query` into a variable and pass that to `mysql_fetch_array`.  You don't just pass it the query string.  Try this:

```
function db_select($prep, $username){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $querycon = "SELECT $prep FROM info_compte WHERE username = '$username'";
        $response = mysql_query($querycon);
        if(!$response){
            echo "Il n\'y a aucun '$username' dans la base de données";
            $response = "";
        }
        else{
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($response, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                    foreach($row as $item)
                    {
                        echo $item.' ';
                    }
                }

        return $response;   
}//db_select
```

UPDATE:

Note as well as the large addition for part 1, I've removed the single quotes around $prep in you SQL statement in part 2.

Read up on `isset()` but also, you can consider using `array_key_exists()`.  I'm not sure on the relative performance comparison of the two.

Comment: All my variable from the `printf` are Undefined Index

Comment: @ThorDozer Then your value of $prep is probably wrong, and it probably shouldn't have single quotes around it.  Are the columns in your info_compte table "username", "suffixe", etc... that you use as array keys?

Comment: @Endophage: yes i verify it four times.

Comment: @Endophage: Yes I'm doing it right now.. But do i really need to do the single quotes around the word in the variable `$prep`?

Comment: @ThorDozer They're not single quotes.  This is a single quote: '  This is a backtick: `  Backticks are used to delineate database, table and column names in SQL.  You don't have to use them but it's a good practice in case at some point you accidentally use an SQL reserved keyword as a column name.  The backticks will make sure SQL doesn't error in that scenario.

Comment: @Endophage: Here's the Error now:Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\Projet Compte Utilisateur\manip_liste.php on line 36
Also, `db_action` return something as 'echo' : "Il n\'y a aucun Test dans la base de données"
But, in my Database, There is a User named `Test`

Comment: @ThorDozer I forgot the ; after `implode()`.  Those are the correct arguments.  Did you also make the necessary updates to $prep from my part 1 code.  $prep should now be an array.  While you may have a user named Test in the database, is that the value in $_POST['username']?

Comment: @Endophage: OK, now  a good line from the database appear but only one time.. because i have two user named `Test` and now all the index `$row['username']`, for example, at the line where's the `printf` is are Undefined

Comment: @Endophage: Correction --> the two appear BUT the checkbox who're not checked appear as undefined Index

Comment: @Endophage: And for your question --> it's the value in `$_POST['username']` to verify if it exists

Comment: @ThorDozer OK, so here's what I believe is the problem.  When you do printf you are trying to print out all the columns regardless of whether the checkbox was checked or not.  If you didn't select that column from your checkboxes it won't exist in the $row array.  Use a foreach to loop over $row and print out the elements.

Comment: @Endophage: I'm a beginner, i need an example

Comment: @ThorDozer I've added an update to the part 2 code with the foreach loop.

Comment: Oh, and I don't know how I missed it earlier, you should use .= not += for concatenating the $tab string.

Comment: @Endophage: Oh, last question --> How can I seperate each row (Like each row have his own line) At then end of each row, we put <br>

Comment: @ThorDozer using a `<br>` would be the normal way to do it.  Alternatively use a table as this is very tabular style data.  However, stick with the <br> for now.  You'll run into fewer problems.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps defining $tab along with $prep at the top will get rid of the "Undefined Variable"-error

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question the `expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given` states that you have given it a string. In your code you have simply given it the values of `$querycon` which is `$querycon = "SELECT '$prep' FROM info_compte WHERE username = '$username'";`
 a string.

You should assign a $variable to the `mysql_query` function and use that in the `mysql_fetch_array` method as the first param.

For the sake of completeness:

To answer your first question, your $tab variable is not being set as that `if` conditional is failing, therefore your attempts at concatenating are throwing errors.

Comment: DONE --> but ..if you look at the 'printf' .. when i execute it...nothing appear except the value of $tab

Comment: @ThorDozer: There's no need to call `mysql_query` twice. Simply assign a variable to it before your first `if` statement. Also, can you do a `var_dump` of the `$row` in the while loop ?

Comment: @Russel Diaz: I'm sorry :S like I said i'm a begginer and also .. i'm French so I don't understand the entire part of your last comment. About the var_dump .. what do i need to do?

Comment: @ThorDozer: `var_dump` is a good way to dump data regarding a variable. I just want to see if `$row` returns anything at all. Because your code looks OK to me ... also, just to be sure, at the start of your document set `error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: @Russel Dias: Every Variable on the line of the `printf` are Undefined Index and the variable  `$row['username']` for example, return nothing (null)

Comment: @ThorDozer: Maybe your query is failing? or the assignment of `$row` to `mysql_fetch_array`